# Link documents attached to a list to another SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, share

I have two different SharePoint list and have maintained a unique Key as a lookup reference to link both the SharePoint list.
Is there a way through which i can link documents attached in List 1 with that of List 2.
List 1 is not a document library.

Sorry for my ignorance if its a silly question, i'm still learning SharePoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2019** then you can use create a new 'Link' feature to link other documents and use them as items in your document library. Trying to open the item will essentially redirect you to the added link.

As per this [Microsoft knowledge article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-link-in-a-document-library-346b1eb9-1e71-4155-80ca-f868d058a56a):

When you're using SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2019, you can add a link in a document library to an item that is located outside the document library. For example, you can add a link to a file or folder located in a different document library, site, or even an external website. When you add a link in a document library, the link shows up in the list of items in that library.

**This feature isn't available in classic SharePoint experience or SharePoint 2016 server or earlier.**

Comment: I guess my question was not clear,I'll give u the actual scenario User 1 creates a new entry against a Ticket in a list attaching his document,details, etc. similarly multiple users create their entries. There's an approval workflow created wherein once approved, the Entry moves to List 2 where a new Team member is assigned to the Ticket.  So the Challenge here is, List2 doesn't carry the attachment from List1, so i need to link both these lists so List2 can have the documents. Can this be done? Currently, the team also upload documents separately in the Document library with the Ticket name.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? Have you already checked custom activities for SharePoint workflows?